# Can't Add Server to a Domain Controller

Tags: router, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, active-directory

I'm running 2 Server 2008 machines, one's my primary DNS/DC and the other will be a DHCP/WDS server (this is for a home environment), but when I try to add my DHCP/WDS server to the Domain, it times out.

I'm running this network on a dlink wired router.

***Error when attempting to add to the domain:***

Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.

The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "testad.local":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.testad.local

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

10.0.0.2
24.226.1.94
24.226.10.194
24.226.10.193

- One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

testad.local
local
. (the root zone)

***Ipconfig /all return:***

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-21-9B-05-D9-8C

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5934:fa2a:fcff:21b6%11(Preferred)

Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.33.182(Preferred)

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234889627

DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-47-44-49-00-21-9B-05-D9-8C

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

***When I run an nslookup on my server, it returns with:***

Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.0.2

*** UnKnown can't find 10.0.0.2: No response from server

I double checked that 10.0.0.2 is DC/DNS server's IP, and it is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your IP address in your `ipconfig /all` is bad.

[Set it to a static IP](http://www.techiwarehouse.com/engine/0a136297/How-to-Assign-Static-IP-Address-in-Windows-Server-2008-R2) in the same range as the DC (10.0.0.3 perhaps). [A DHCP server must always have a static IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755277.aspx), because without a valid network connection it cannot ask itself for DHCP services.

`169.254.33.182` is a [Zero-Conf/AVAHI/Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) address, and will not work with other devices unless they too are using zeroconf addresses and services.

Windows uses Zeroconf address as a fallback when the system is set to be a DHCP client, but cannot reach a DHCP server.

Comment: wonderful. feel free to upvote and accept.

Comment: Can't accept quite yet, but I will do!